# Interacting between javascript and JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf

I'm developing an application with jsf and Jquery. It has a Jplayer "player" for audio files.

I have to implement a track syncronization for the lyric.

When the user press a key, Jquery fill an array with the current time:

`arraySync.push($("#jquery_jplayer_N").data().jPlayer.status.currentTime);`

My question is, how can I send this javascript array to the JSF bean for persistance it into database?

Im pretty new with Jquery, the lyric for the song is accessing through JSON file created on a bean:

```
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(letras2));
//json=json.replaceAll("\"","");
try {
    //write converted json data to a file named "file.json"
    String path=System.getProperty("catalina.base");
                path=path+"\\media\\file"+album.getId()+".json";
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
    mJSONArray.write(writer);

    writer.close();
}
```

Is this right, or im missing something?

How can I create the JSON file using Jquery(and a JSF bean) or how can i send my javascript array to a bean method?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is about: setting a jsf bean property to a javascript array? What does that have to do with generating a file?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if its a good pratice to create a JSON object in a jsf bean and write it as file as seen before and then access it through Jquery. Now i want to do reversive mode, i mean, create the JSON object with Jquery and write it in a file with a jsf bean.

Its necessary write the file to access it(jsf bean and js/Jquery) as JSON object, or how can i access this JSON object whitout writing it as file?

Comment: What I do is just serializing my javascript object into a `<h:inputHidden>` with `JSON.stringify()` before submitting the form and deserializing it on the server side. Most simple method possible. But I'm still not sure if that's what you actually want?

Comment: Thank you! Thats what i wanted to know if there was another way to access JSON whitout creating the file in the server. Now i see that the greates way is serializing the JSON object with the inputHidden as you say.

Problem solved!